# Proof that the set of transference plans is closed in the weak topology

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence, optimal-transport, weak-topology

I am reading Villani's *Optimal transport: Old and new*.

Theorem 4.1 concerns the existence of an optimal coupling between any two Polish probability spaces $(\mathcal{X}, \mu)$ and $(\mathcal{Y}, \nu)$. The proof begins as follows (note that $P(\mathcal{X})$ denotes the set of probability distributions on $\mathcal{X}$, and $\Pi(\mu, \nu)$ the set of all joint distributions on $\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y}$ with marginals $\mu$ and $\nu$ respectively):

> Since $\mathcal{X}$ is Polish, $\{\mu\}$ is tight in $P(\mathcal{X})$; similarly, $\{\nu\}$ is tight in $P(\mathcal{Y})$. By Lemma 4.4, $\Pi(\mu, \nu)$ is tight in $P(\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y})$, and by Prokhorov's theorem this set has a compact closure. By passing to the limit in the equation for marginals, we see that $\Pi(\mu, \nu)$ is closed, so it is in fact *compact*.

I am trying to understand the last claim ("By passing to the limit...") - it is unclear what "equation for marginals" is referred to here. **Essentially, the thing I want to show is that $\Pi(\mu, \nu)$ is closed in the weak topology.**

The best I can do is as follows: suppose we have $\pi_k \to \pi$ in the weak topology, with each $\pi_k \in \Pi(\mu, \nu)$. Then for any $\mu$-measurable $A$, we have $\pi_k(A \times \mathcal{Y}) = \mu(A)$ (and similarly for $\nu$), so we would be done *if* we have $\pi_k(A \times \mathcal{Y}) \to \pi(A \times \mathcal{Y})$.

However, as far as I understand, weak convergence of $\pi_k$ to $\pi$ only ensures  $\pi_k(B) \to \pi(B)$ when $\pi(\partial B) = 0$ (with $\partial B$ denoting the boundary of $B$). Presumably there will be $A$ such that $A \times \mathcal{Y}$ does not satisfy this, for instance.

Can anyone see how to make sense of this "passing to the limit" step, or how else to obtain this result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is easiest to prove it this way:

> **Proposition 1.** A sequence of probability measures $\mu_n$ on a Polish space $X$ converges weakly to a probability measure $\mu$ iff $\int f\,d\mu_n \to \int f\,d\mu$ for every bounded continuous $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$.  (This is part of the portmanteau theorem.)
>
> **Proposition 2.** Suppose $\mu_1, \mu_2$ are probability measures on a Polish space $X$.  If $\int f\,d\mu_1 = \int f\,d\mu_2$ for every bounded continuous $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$, then $\mu_1 = \mu_2$.  (Proof sketch: let $E \subset X$ be closed and fix a compatible metric $d$.  By taking $f(x) = \max(1 - n d(x, E), 0)$ and letting $n \to \infty$ with dominated convergence, conclude that $\mu_1(E) = \mu_2(E)$.  Now use a monotone class argument to conclude $\mu_1 = \mu_2$.)

Now in your setup, let $f : \mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{R}$ be an arbitrary bounded continuous function.  By assumption we have $\int_{\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y}} f(x)\,\pi_k(dx,dy) = \int_{\mathcal{X}} f(x)\,\mu(dx)$ for each $k$.  Letting $k \to \infty$ and using Proposition 1, we have $\int_{\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y}} f(x)\,\pi(dx,dy) = \int_{\mathcal{X}} f(x)\,\mu(dx)$ as well.  Now Proposition 2 tells us $\pi(\cdot \times \mathcal{Y}) = \mu$.

---

Here is another way:

> **Proposition 3.** Let $\mu, \nu$ be two Borel probability measures on a metrizable space $X$.  Suppose that for all Borel sets $B$ with $\mu(\partial B) = \nu(\partial B) = 0$, we have $\mu(B) = \nu(B)$.  Then $\mu = \nu$.

*Proof.*  Use the Dynkin $\pi$-$\lambda$ lemma.  Let $\mathcal{L} = \{B \in \mathcal{B} : \mu(B) = \nu(B)\}$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra; it is routine to show that $\mathcal{L}$ is a $\lambda$-system.

Now let $\mathcal{P} = \{ B \in \mathcal{B} : \mu(\partial B) = \nu(\partial B) = 0\}$.  By assumption, $\mathcal{P} \subset \mathcal{L}$.
For $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{P}$, we have $\partial(B_1 \cap B_2) \subset \partial B_1 \cup \partial B_2$ and thus $B_1 \cap B_2 \in \mathcal{P}$, so $\mathcal{P}$ is a $\pi$-system.

We have to show that $\sigma(\mathcal{P}) = \mathcal{B}$.  Fix a compatible metric; it suffices to show that every open ball is in $\sigma(\mathcal{P})$.  Fix $x \in X$ and let $B(x,r)$ denote the open ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$.  Note that the boundaries $\partial B(x,r), r > 0$ are pairwise disjoint, so the set $R_x^\mu = \{r > 0 : \mu(\partial B(x,r)) > 0\}$ is at most countable, and the same for $R_x^\nu$.  So the set $S = (0,\infty) \setminus (R_x^\mu \cup R_x^\nu)$ is dense in $(0, \infty)$.  Hence for any $r > 0$ we can find $r_n \in S$ with $r_n \uparrow r$.  Then $B(x,r_n) \in \mathcal{P}$ and $\bigcup_n B(x,r_n) = B(x,r)$.  So $B(x,r) \in \sigma(\mathcal{P})$, where $x,r$ were arbitrary.

By Dynkin's lemma we conclude that $\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{L}$ which is to say that $\mu = \nu$.