# Set of transport plans is closed in the weak topology

Tags: measure-theory, optimal-transport

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are Polish spaces and $\mu$ and $\nu$ are probability measures respectively on $X$ and $Y$. Define
$$ \Gamma(\mu, \nu) = \{ \pi \in \mathcal{P}(X \times Y) \mid \pi(A \times Y) = \mu(A) \, , \, \pi(X \times B) = \nu(B) \quad \forall \, (A,B) \in \mathcal{B}(X) \times \mathcal{B}(Y) \} $$
i.e. the space of probability measures on the product that have $\mu$ and $\nu$ as marginals. 
I want to prove that this set is closed w.r.t. the weak topology of measures. In this question:
[Proof that the set of transference plans is closed in the weak topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2402520/proof-that-the-set-of-transference-plans-is-closed-in-the-weak-topology) was proved that if $\{\pi_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \Gamma(\mu, \nu)$ are s.t. $\pi_n \rightharpoonup \pi$ then $\pi$ has $\mu$ and $\nu$ as marginals.

Is it enough? Shouldn't I prove also that $\pi$ is a positive measure? How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-negative measures form a closed subset of the set of all signed/complex measures w.r.t. weak convergence. Hence any weak limit of Probability measures is automatically a positive mesure measure. Since $\int 1 d\pi_n \to \int 1d\pi$ it follows that $\pi$ is necessarily a probability measure.

Comment: No, I am o only assuming $\pi$ is a (possibily signed) finite measure

Comment: Ok, thank you. Do you know where I can find a proof of this?

Comment: And, what you wrote, does imply that the set of probability measures is closed in the weak topology?

Comment: Yes, if $\pi_n$ is a probability measure for each $n$ and $\int f d\pi_n \to \int f d\pi$ for every bounded continuous function $f$ then $\int f d\pi \geq 0$ for all such $f$. From this it is fairly easy to show that $\pi (C) \geq 0$ for every close set and finally that $\pi (E) \geq 0$ for every Borel set e$E$. I don't know any place where this is explicitly written down but this is folklore.

Comment: I tried to search it on the internet but I can't find a proof anywhere. In particular, I  need two facts:
1. $\mu_n \rightharpoonup \mu$ implies $0 \le \limsup_n \mu_n(C) \le \mu(C)$ for every closed set. In the proof monotone convergence on $\mu$ is used. Does it work even if $\mu$ is a signed measure?
2. Every finite signed measure on a Polish space is regular (so that i can approximate the measure of a Borel set with closed sets contained in it). Is it true?

Comment: Let $C$ be  a closed set and $C_r=\{x: d(x,C) <r\}$. There exist  a continuous function $f$ such that $0\leq f \leq 1$, $f(x)=1$ for all $x \in C$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x \notin C_r$. Since $\int f d\mu =\lim \int f d\mu_n \geq 0$ we get $\mu (C)+\int_{C_r\setminus C} f d\mu \geq 0$. As $ r$ decreases to $0$ the second term tends to $0$. Hence $\mu (C) \geq 0$.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not very confident with signed measures. For example, if $\mu$ was positive it was immediate for me to note that the secondo term tends to $0$. Being $\mu$ signed, I need to check it (maybe Jordan decomposition is enough to conclude).
So now, how can i pass from closed sets to general Borel sets?

Comment: If $\mu$ is a signed measure and $E_n$ decreses to the empty set then $\mu (E_n) \to 0$. This is because a finite signed measure is a difference of two positive measures. For passing to Borel sets there are several standard techniques. One is the Dynkin's $\pi -\lambda$ theorem.

Comment: Ok, Now I have completely understood. Thank you very much!!